# Is there a Visual Studio Load Test open source equivalent - or something close?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, testing

In Visual Studio Team Edition there is a load test tool where you can select unit tests, integration tests etc... to form scenarios which are then used in a load test session with different configurations for example varying usage levels.

Looking at for example the NUnit framework, it would be possible to develop a form of such a tool, along with a base load testing code base, but I was interested if anyone knows of any open source project which has has already done a similar thing which could then be of use for this situation and possibly extended?

Cheers for now,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
http://www.webload.org/

It's only a load tester, not also built with Unit Tests, Integration Tests, etc - However how about a Continuous Integration setup with CruiseControl.NET as your CI Server which would run automated builds and carry out the tests and then use Webload for your load testing? You can certainly get CruiseControl.NET to run external tools - but IDK whether or not Webload has a console which could automatically run the load tests for you - but it probably could ;)